# need code to Convert rupee to dollar in java 

Tags: java, web-services

I am writing an application java ,
 is any way to write a java code  to convert rupee to u.s. dollar and it shoud fetch the current u.s. dollar.
I need the program in java

Thanks

Comment: What does this mean? Do you want a rough estimate? Or do you actually want to exchange currency? The number of dollars you get for your rupees depends on who's doing the exchange, when they do it, what their commission is, etc.

Comment: -1: No code sample for what you've tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll either hardcode the exchange rate in your application or database, or you'll be fetching that in real time (or asynchronously & cache every x minutes) from a third party site, for example http://www.google.com/search?q=1+usd+in+inr

Comment: fetch the result into a string and parse (probably using a regex).

Answer (score 4):

Google is our friend.  I found this webservice which offers currency conhttp://www.webservicex.net/WS/WSDetails.aspx?WSID=10

Comment: Just a note: Strange, not all codes of ISO 4217 are listed in enumeration, e.g. I do not see Belarusian Ruble (BYR). It should be in the list at least, but the service may return "cannot convert". Ah, americans...

Comment: There might be better services out there, that was the first one that came up in my search.

Answer (score 2):

In order to do this you would need to fetch the current exchange rate from a web service. The easiest way, if you just need to fetch a page, is something like this:

```
InputStream is = new URL("http://someexchangesite.com...").openStream();
```

Then read and parse the [InputStream](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) to find the exchange rate, and then use it with some simple multiplication!

Answer (score 0):

**Please find the below code which returns json response for getting Conversion Rate.**

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();       

NameValuePair arg1 = new NameValuePair("method","runJob");

//Change your currency types here in which you would want to convert

NameValuePair arg2 = new NameValuePair("from","USD");
NameValuePair arg3 = new NameValuePair("to", "PKR");

//getting the method
GetMethod method = new GetMethod("http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency");
method.setQueryString(new NameValuePair[]{arg1, arg2, arg3});

//executes the link
client.executeMethod(method);

//getting response in string
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(method.getResponseBodyAsString());

//getting rate from the json response
double rate = obj.getDouble("rate");

//closing conncetion
method.releaseConnection();     


//returning value
return rate;
```